# Incorrect row return when using offset on an indexed column (sqlite)

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net

I have a sqlite table such as below:

[image]

Case A: indexNum is primary key, autoincrement. 
When I execute the statement

```
"select StaffID from FingerprintDataTest limit 1 offset 13"
```

the return staffID is 5789 which is correct.

Case B:
indexNum is primary key, autoincrement.
StaffID is indexed column.

When I execute the statement

```
 "select StaffID from FingerprintDataTest limit 1 offset 13"
```

the return staffID is 1413 which is not the StaffID I want.

I want to index the StaffID column to make query for StaffID faster in case of large data. However, it is messing up my search using offset. Can anyone advice me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `order by`. (My guess is you want `order by indexNum`, so you have `select StaffID from FingerprintDataTest order by indexNum limit 1 offset 13`)

Without `order by`, any row can be returned. It's indeterminate. A table is a set of records, not a list of records. There is no inherent order in the table.

Comment: Yeah it seems to work now. I am no expert in database concept. But, why is it when I remove index from StaffID column the statement "select StaffID from FingerprintDataTest limit 1 offset 13" works correctly?

Comment: @Ytan when `indexNum` is the only key, SQLite probably scans through all data in the order of `indexNum`. When there are more keys, SQLite reads in a different order. But this is SQLite's internal logic. You cannot rely on it. You only rely on what SQLite promises. In the first case the result "accidentally" matches your expectation.